# Dynamic minlength attribute in angular 4

Tags: angular, validation

I am developing angular 4 application. I want to make my input value minimum length dynamic. It needs to set it in some configurable file. In my component, I am reading it and copied it in some variable. Now I need to set that variable as minLength attribute. But its not working. Can some body help me to figure out issue here. Thanks in advance.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="emp.firstName" required name="firstName"  #firstnameEl="ngModel" minlength= "nameMinLength">
```

Component:

```
this.nameMinLength = UserSettings.NAME_MIN_LENGTH;
console.log("Minimum length is" + this.nameMinLength);
```

Here  on console , I am getting correct values as 12.

Comment: can you add your component

Comment: Updated with component

Answer (score 2):

Use Attribute binding instead like this

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="emp.firstName" required name="firstName"  #firstnameEl="ngModel" [minlength]= "nameMinLength">
```

Now you are simply assigning a value to attribute not dynamically.
To achieve this you have to set using attribute binding.

```
[minlength]= "nameMinLength"
```

or

```
minlength= {{nameMinLength}}
```

Comment: It is like my question. Can I make dynamic `#firstnameEl="ngModel"`. because of which inside ngFor. Example `#firstnameEl_1="ngModel"`.. `#firstnameEl_2="ngModel"`

Comment: @CycDemo I don't think so you can create dynamic `#firstnameEl="ngModel` reason is this is not something like variable binding. But I am not fully sure If something is hack for this